# How to make scipy.optimize.curve_fit result in a better sine regression fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a problem where I am using scipy.optimize.curve_fit to do a regression fit to a sine/cosine function but the fit does not seem as optimized as I want it to be. How can I change my code to make the fitting better?

I have already tried changing how parameters are tried for the dataset and there is always seemingly a difference in phase-offset of my generated fit or the fitting function is not fitting to the proper minima/maxima.

Here is the code I am using to generate the regression fit. The output (fitfunc) can be plotted to show the result.

```py
def sin_regress(data_x, data_y):
    """Function regression fits data to SIN function; does not need guess of freq.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data_x :
        Data for X values, most likely a set of voltages.
    data_y :
        Data for Y values, most likely the resulting powers from voltages.

    Returns
    -------
    __ :
        Dictionary containing values for amplitude, angular frequency, phase, offset, frequency, period, fit function, max covariance, initial guess.

    """
    data_x = np.array(data_x)
    data_y = np.array(data_y)
    freqz = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(data_x), (data_x[1] - data_x[0])) # uniform spacing
    freq_y = abs(np.fft.rfft(data_y))
    guess_freq = abs(freqz[np.argmax(freq_y[1:])+1]) # exclude offset peak
    guess_amp = np.std(data_y) * 2.**0.5
    guess_offset = np.mean(data_y)
    guess = np.array([guess_amp, 2.*np.pi*guess_freq, 0., guess_offset])

    def sinfunc(t, A, w, p, c):
        """Raw function to be used to fit data.

        Parameters
        ----------
        t :
            Voltage array
        A :
            Amplitude
        w :
            Angular frequency
        p :
            Phase
        c :
            Constant value

        Returns
        -------
        __ :
            Formed fit function with provided values.

        """
        return A * np.sin(w*t + p) + c

    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(sinfunc, data_x, data_y, p0=guess)
    A, w, p, c = popt
    f = w/(2.*np.pi)
    fitfunc = lambda t: A * np.sin(w*t + p) + c
    return {"amp": A, "omega": w, "phase": p, "offset": c, "freq": f, "period": 1./f, "fitfunc": fitfunc, "maxcov": np.max(pcov), "rawres": (guess,popt,pcov)}
```

With my trial dataset being:

```py
x = np.linspace(3.5,9.5,(9.5-3.5)/0.00625 + 1)


pow1 = [1.8262110863, 1.80944546009, 1.7970185646900003, 1.77120336754, 1.7458101235699999, 1.73597098224, 1.7122529922799998, 1.70015674142, 1.68968617429, 1.6989396515, 1.69760676076, 1.6946375613599998, 1.6895321899, 1.68145658386, 1.68581793183, 1.6920468775900002, 1.6865452951599997, 1.68570953338, 1.6922784791700003, 1.70958957412, 1.71683408637, 1.70360183933, 1.6919669752199997, 1.6669487117300001, 1.6351298032300001, 1.6061729066600001, 1.57344333403, 1.54723708217, 1.5277773737599998, 1.5122628414300001, 1.4962354965200002, 1.4873367459, 1.47567715522, 1.4696584634, 1.46159565032, 1.45320592315, 1.4487225244200002, 1.44572887186, 1.44089260198, 1.4367157657399998, 1.4349226211, 1.43614316806, 1.4381950627400002, 1.43947658627, 1.4483572314200002, 1.4504305909200002, 1.44436990692, 1.43367609757, 1.42637295252, 1.41197427963, 1.4067529511399999, 1.39714414185, 1.38309980493, 1.3730701362500004, 1.3693239836499997, 1.3729558979599998, 1.38291189477, 1.3988274622900003, 1.42112832324, 1.44217266068, 1.4578792438300001, 1.46478639274, 1.46676801398, 1.4646383458800003, 1.45918801344, 1.44561402809, 1.4212145146499997, 1.4012453921299999, 1.38070199226, 1.36215759642, 1.3540496661500003, 1.35470913884, 1.3481165993199997, 1.34059081754, 1.332964567, 1.33426054366, 1.34052562222, 1.3343255632100002, 1.3310385903, 1.33044179339, 1.32827462527, 1.3356201140500001, 1.3400144893900001, 1.3157198001600001, 1.27716313727, 1.2517667292400003, 1.2406836620500001, 1.2354036030700002, 1.23110776291, 1.22492582889, 1.22074838719, 1.21816502762, 1.21015135518, 1.20038737012, 1.1920263929700001, 1.18723010357, 1.19656731125, 1.2237068834899998, 1.2373841696199999, 1.2251076648299999, 1.1963014909299998, 1.16152861736, 1.13940556893, 1.12839812676, 1.12368066547, 1.1190219542100002, 1.11384679759, 1.10555781262, 1.0977575386300003, 1.0901734365399998, 1.0824275375699999, 1.07552931443, 1.0696565210100002, 1.06481394254, 1.0578173014299999, 1.05204230102, 1.0482530038799998, 1.04237087457, 1.0361766944300002, 1.0297906393, 1.0240842912299999, 1.01250548183, 0.9964340353700001, 0.9859450307400002, 0.98614987451, 0.9826424718800002, 0.9739505767299999, 0.9578738177999998, 0.9416973908799999, 0.92975112051, 0.9204409049900001, 0.91821299468, 0.9100360995600001, 0.89589154778, 0.8799530701000002, 0.8640439088, 0.8500274234399999, 0.8428500205999999, 0.8358678326, 0.8333072464999999, 0.83420148485, 0.8362578717, 0.83608947323, 0.83035464861, 0.82315039029, 0.81220152235, 0.80169300598, 0.7918658959, 0.7808782388700001, 0.77684747687, 0.7743299962, 0.76797978094, 0.7591097217, 0.7520710688500001, 0.7452609707, 0.73562753255, 0.7256206568399999, 0.71663518742, 0.70951165178, 0.7035884873, 0.6973768853, 0.6900439160299999, 0.68062538021, 0.67096725454, 0.66585371901, 0.6663177033900001, 0.67214877804, 0.6787934074299999, 0.68365489213, 0.68581510712, 0.6820892084400001, 0.67805153237, 0.67540688376, 0.6724865515, 0.6674502035, 0.6593852224500001, 0.6524835227400001, 0.64758563177, 0.6424489126599999, 0.63385426361, 0.6242639699699999, 0.6143974848999999, 0.60705328516, 0.60087306988, 0.5928024247700001, 0.5864009594799999, 0.5786877362899999, 0.57457744302, 0.57012636848, 0.56554310644, 0.5618750202299999, 0.55731189492, 0.55057384756, 0.5419996086800001, 0.52987726408, 0.51025575876, 0.48599474143000004, 0.46231124366000004, 0.44151899608999995, 0.42632008877, 0.42655368254, 0.42784393651999997, 0.42863940533999995, 0.42506971759, 0.41952014686999994, 0.41337420894, 0.40570705996, 0.39706149294, 0.38721395321, 0.3806321949, 0.37313342483999995, 0.36982676447, 0.36704194004, 0.36189430296, 0.3560628963, 0.34954350131, 0.34540695806, 0.34178605934, 0.33629549256, 0.3293877577, 0.32357672213, 0.31864117490000005, 0.31165906503, 0.30439039263000006, 0.29875160317, 0.29294459105000004, 0.28847285244, 0.28509162173, 0.28265949265, 0.28003828154, 0.27814630873999996, 0.27599048828, 0.27524025386, 0.27406833971, 0.27281988259, 0.27155314420999993, 0.26840999947000005, 0.2634181241, 0.25883622926000005, 0.25503165868, 0.25056988104, 0.24466620872, 0.23932761459000002, 0.23422685251999997, 0.22880456697, 0.22310130485000004, 0.21785542557999998, 0.21366651902000006, 0.20966530780999998, 0.20521315906, 0.20012157666000002, 0.19469597081, 0.18957032591999995, 0.18423432945, 0.17946309866000001, 0.17845044232, 0.17746098912000002, 0.17475331315, 0.17039776599, 0.16363173032999997, 0.15716942518, 0.15214176858, 0.14870803788, 0.14515563527000003, 0.14218680693, 0.13893215828, 0.13546723615, 0.13178983356, 0.12747471604, 0.12350983297, 0.12011202021999998, 0.11627787931000003, 0.11218377746, 0.10821276155, 0.10384311280999999, 0.09960625706000001, 0.09615194041000003, 0.09216061199, 0.08847719376999999, 0.08481545522999999, 0.08163922452000001, 0.07851820869000001, 0.07535195845, 0.07259346216999998, 0.06996658694999999, 0.06748611806, 0.06513859836, 0.06343437948, 0.06174502390000001, 0.059727113600000006, 0.05755100017, 0.054968070300000005, 0.052386214650000006, 0.05002439809, 0.04768410494, 0.04532047195999999, 0.04319275697, 0.04105023728, 0.03894787384, 0.03695523698, 0.03513302983, 0.033548459399999994, 0.032170295249999994, 0.030958654539999998, 0.02983605681, 0.028375548879999997, 0.02671830267, 0.024898224419999997, 0.0230959196, 0.02139548979, 0.01983882955, 0.018419727860000002, 0.017108712149999997, 0.01590183706, 0.01467630964, 0.01340369235, 0.01204181727, 0.011048145310000002, 0.01072443434, 0.010401953859999999, 0.010151465580000001, 0.00990748117, 0.00972232492, 0.00956939523, 0.009442617850000001, 0.009344043619999999, 0.009241641279999999, 0.00915107487, 0.009064981109999998, 0.008985430320000001, 0.00890431702, 0.00883441469, 0.008775488880000001, 0.00873752015, 0.00871498109, 0.008710938120000001, 0.00872328188, 0.00874796935, 0.008778945909999999, 0.00882859436, 0.00889468812, 0.00898683656, 0.00910033268, 0.009214043629999998, 0.00934455143, 0.00949293034, 0.00965939522, 0.009844610069999999, 0.01005115305, 0.010290684330000001, 0.01054888746, 0.010822364050000002, 0.011132617979999999, 0.012252539939999998, 0.013524844710000001, 0.01492336044, 0.01639437616, 0.01790093876, 0.01949634904, 0.02112754055, 0.022849025059999997, 0.02457990408, 0.02637656436, 0.02816101762, 0.02999357634, 0.031735392870000004, 0.03370418208999999, 0.03591160409, 0.03868365509, 0.0413049248, 0.043746897629999996, 0.04622211263, 0.04871939798, 0.051123460649999994, 0.05370180068, 0.05625859775000001, 0.058868656510000006, 0.06136678167, 0.06394643029, 0.06623680155999997, 0.06885605955999999, 0.07171654804, 0.07483811078, 0.07798461489, 0.08075584557000001, 0.08390440047999999, 0.08690709601, 0.09012059232, 0.09292447923, 0.09569860054, 0.09869240932999998, 0.10204307363999998, 0.10579037859, 0.10944262493000001, 0.11339190256000002, 0.11739889503, 0.12165444219999999, 0.12640639566999998, 0.13103823193000003, 0.13545668928, 0.13980243177, 0.1445100493, 0.14892381914000002, 0.15358704212000002, 0.15754780411999997, 0.1620275896, 0.16721823448, 0.17344235602999997, 0.17972712208000002, 0.18671513038999998, 0.19370331449, 0.1997322407, 0.20632862788999998, 0.21168169468000003, 0.2186676522, 0.22613634413, 0.23308478213, 0.24056257561, 0.24694894328, 0.25289726401, 0.26043587782, 0.26523394455, 0.27115650357, 0.27472996084, 0.27757628917, 0.28195025433, 0.28717476642, 0.29255468867, 0.29700002103, 0.29903203287999996, 0.30043668141, 0.30362955273000003, 0.30861634997000004, 0.3146493582, 0.32141648759, 0.33050709371, 0.34155311010999995, 0.35347176329, 0.3641544984300001, 0.37273471389, 0.37810184317999995, 0.38245108175, 0.38773739072, 0.39195147307000006, 0.39284567233, 0.39723110233000003, 0.39968268453, 0.40089368072000003, 0.40181627844999995, 0.40374096608, 0.40828194296, 0.41598909193000005, 0.42570815513, 0.43468223779000004, 0.4419052070599999, 0.44814120359, 0.4541516141699999, 0.45904682936999996, 0.46598345094999993, 0.47421183044, 0.48259810056, 0.49064425346, 0.49772194929999997, 0.50355609034, 0.5097226337399999, 0.5242588261700001, 0.53191943219, 0.5427558587299999, 0.5558334377799999, 0.57145400528, 0.58596031492, 0.6017949058700001, 0.61620852018, 0.62886383358, 0.63983492811, 0.64928899126, 0.65807748798, 0.66440410952, 0.67291110232, 0.68452424766, 0.6952567679499999, 0.7045326279799999, 0.7168566913700001, 0.72438360596, 0.7334800323799999, 0.73850692728, 0.7444589784699999, 0.75250327593, 0.7652333354299999, 0.7794230629700001, 0.79152575915, 0.80011656054, 0.80971581904, 0.8176350188100001, 0.82681863275, 0.83466310596, 0.84169904395, 0.85246648611, 0.8612931078200001, 0.8712971515300001, 0.88083937874, 0.89039777788, 0.89838717297, 0.90641512274, 0.9111584238600001, 0.9159304749999999, 0.9210217253499999, 0.92296264345, 0.9233887177, 0.9218466277399999, 0.9176133266600001, 0.91940151039, 0.9208485417400001, 0.9220888543199999, 0.9236718817800001, 0.9276074484799999, 0.93015244864, 0.9343631130099999, 0.93763016402, 0.9384009648400001, 0.93879867973, 0.93652442175, 0.93662918739, 0.9331820972899999, 0.93503584744, 0.9360406912399999, 0.93994795716, 0.9444487777899999, 0.95150762595, 0.9574753021500001, 0.9659650293199998, 0.9757605964, 0.9878513785299999, 0.99883880117, 1.01323052095, 1.0311493112499999, 1.04763474212, 1.0677277318200002, 1.086237323, 1.0988490621599998, 1.10287175775, 1.11006095748, 1.1203823058799998, 1.1266948453599999, 1.1295011150999998, 1.13468379124, 1.13839008058, 1.1417559206699999, 1.1386140845, 1.1368738695300002, 1.13791410398, 1.1443759989699998, 1.1533826011700001, 1.16127430094, 1.1771807669, 1.19318348288, 1.2014892452, 1.20715822998, 1.21764737132, 1.23158125907, 1.2387470993899998, 1.2441262208700001, 1.2562376475, 1.2682344256899998, 1.28293907518, 1.2903573374300001, 1.3040509126199997, 1.3260814219800001, 1.3595052134299999, 1.3870089263099998, 1.4040962907899999, 1.4190098465199998, 1.43005375357, 1.4343605702800002, 1.4355429141099998, 1.43638377355, 1.44962018073, 1.45147113789, 1.45921588453, 1.4661880139399999, 1.47414703793, 1.47941295628, 1.47950143284, 1.4748920184699998, 1.4692222329000004, 1.4631299473100001, 1.45757789614, 1.4527345168899999, 1.4434376802999997, 1.4390123479299999, 1.4387321330999998, 1.4376372501999999, 1.44922049319, 1.46122473234, 1.47480432313, 1.48463330822, 1.50740325124, 1.52143227566, 1.5388702456399996, 1.5586354228100001, 1.5670929624799999, 1.57654938893, 1.60239005482, 1.6187282200499997, 1.6195258763400002, 1.6341473226799998, 1.6455264836499999, 1.6550699218299996, 1.6682315829299998, 1.68167279482, 1.6900114477300001, 1.6978344170500002, 1.7018968392199998, 1.70642375358, 1.71237959385, 1.7205134225500003, 1.7311321537799997, 1.7430771546100001, 1.7517999091500003, 1.76491293742, 1.7833902824799999, 1.8081253623500004, 1.83075608662, 1.8524498577000004, 1.86711454623, 1.8814965784800002, 1.8857294108200002, 1.90378495898, 1.9156142957500002, 1.9241271088399998, 1.92694429655, 1.92836076148, 1.9246632612399999, 1.9177767372999999, 1.9240789057399996, 1.93491201195, 1.95508541182, 1.9667632837499998, 1.97663894849, 1.9838888513599997, 1.9862320351100002, 1.9850681678399997, 1.9724571903800001, 1.9569690057000002, 1.9450577939199998, 1.93385585952, 1.91272038928, 1.90263962687, 1.89419806376, 1.8846363638699999, 1.8752989218, 1.8721239020399998, 1.87465480067, 1.87635644139, 1.8883053875500004, 1.90622687322, 1.9326186524100002, 1.96217418184, 1.99341387155, 2.0052843606899997, 2.0198940101400003, 2.03224112041, 2.04585828934, 2.0482686606100002, 2.0761935844499995, 2.10636661393, 2.1218703845699998, 2.1265723770799996, 2.13344606897, 2.13480411595, 2.12395452534, 2.11298829408, 2.10366419185, 2.10279155509, 2.10582569592, 2.12401487691, 2.14351597204, 2.1603280826, 2.1732762280399998, 2.1829961701499996, 2.1825562873100006, 2.1829598615399997, 2.18269224434, 2.18542837733, 2.18136038877, 2.17195739983, 2.16672507523, 2.1595190200499994, 2.15408655871, 2.16100126623, 2.1646243915, 2.16989273172, 2.1760575368399997, 2.18993197141, 2.20082640578, 2.18953400264, 2.1673666182699995, 2.15301331645, 2.1344672799800004, 2.1212936853000004, 2.1081594070399996, 2.08825354625, 2.0697085058700004, 2.045492469, 2.02153998684, 2.0038663723099996, 2.0038828566799998, 2.0085019585599997, 2.0192783851200002, 2.03833670679, 2.05771370034, 2.08050465897, 2.1006803439999997, 2.1263974552, 2.14748327701, 2.17287144288, 2.1941383974899997, 2.19820122981, 2.2003345112000003, 2.20800316408, 2.21184328157, 2.21310867227, 2.21112832057, 2.1998480658600004, 2.1906804089599996, 2.17670294702, 2.1515223983699996, 2.1337058932199997, 2.11742559909, 2.1017357932899996, 2.0798991511200002, 2.05328198125, 2.02510619803, 2.00362619651, 1.98193234731, 1.9618359005700001, 1.9612528146099997, 1.97096636996, 1.9761617414300001, 1.9782324642600002, 1.99263889104, 2.00500029816, 2.01506871685, 2.02912785846, 2.04221860157, 2.06368362263, 2.07491317421, 2.08832055797, 2.09538342956, 2.1084886843899997, 2.1158979036700005, 2.1260576895499996, 2.13639327622, 2.14181249535, 2.1392352295499997, 2.14448495648, 2.1421138235, 2.14009620617, 2.1384934521399996, 2.1319765571600002, 2.1216323962400003, 2.1065051490999998, 2.08999485498, 2.06996758792, 2.05396301646, 2.0366352808700006, 2.023489069, 1.9927697308899996, 1.9807445347400001, 1.97629449536, 1.9772154719699997, 1.9837454333899998, 1.9903514690000002, 1.9990068602399997, 2.0052703762999995, 2.0102515290099996, 2.01071088451, 2.00780344289, 2.00202451671, 1.99526703575, 1.9894158244, 1.9859053554, 1.9872483633099995, 1.99006639085, 2.00697930222, 2.0329301048299997, 2.05059264513, 2.0540770985099996, 2.04176762498, 2.0093012359700007, 1.9757453156100002, 1.94977980597, 1.94015615295, 1.93165724611, 1.9207719523600002, 1.90945249843, 1.89062300491, 1.87690150004, 1.8621346825699998, 1.84607821661, 1.828253313, 1.8169694254700002, 1.8075289169999997, 1.8040289362800004, 1.79267489253, 1.78023102445, 1.7778953016200003, 1.7787011610500003, 1.78226670819, 1.7830425676100004, 1.77486727406, 1.7675372149399997, 1.7575688744100002, 1.7498299871300003, 1.74518012353, 1.73248096246, 1.7160241253800002, 1.70317674164, 1.6978293584500002, 1.6946921121299998, 1.6961595927200002, 1.70211670251, 1.7104493398199998, 1.7203816647499999, 1.7274331496, 1.7311123100199999, 1.73665119714, 1.74750018228, 1.7625600270900001, 1.76829838689, 1.7683754962599998, 1.7604641870999997, 1.7378729159800002, 1.7182883638100002, 1.7072806677199999, 1.7037852573199999, 1.6963237919299996, 1.67904111493, 1.64849412058, 1.61509034869, 1.58860298353, 1.56708077499, 1.5563275906199998, 1.5508352464699997, 1.5448227655799998, 1.53880546048, 1.54041544105, 1.5403843473000003, 1.53577729621, 1.5273169831, 1.51722079097, 1.5010415320300001, 1.4873523904299997, 1.47098713536, 1.45343877476, 1.4333900233299999, 1.4214382256099998, 1.4199358231499999, 1.42357822576, 1.42446916333, 1.4169634987200002, 1.40651060735, 1.39602957147, 1.38608337936, 1.38502109414, 1.38722933647, 1.3877573052599999, 1.38915685615, 1.3879546490299999, 1.38030042971, 1.37484574183, 1.36882917891, 1.36771619056, 1.36598312403, 1.35475238104, 1.3352715984299999, 1.31243304213, 1.29205091175, 1.26981483599, 1.25096920963, 1.23261465755, 1.2107178005399999, 1.1896016271599998, 1.1758782668, 1.17342422369, 1.17358562993, 1.17110207509, 1.1674486178099999, 1.1603703751, 1.1565048865399998, 1.15140617524, 1.15148740571, 1.15832875386, 1.16650391071, 1.1712949266600001, 1.16865191865, 1.16596408644, 1.1661593208199998, 1.16419447693, 1.15754447647, 1.15312982771, 1.1506705697300001, 1.14375644814, 1.13705099847, 1.12589113437, 1.11212277402, 1.10001296849, 1.08946394429, 1.0747068729400002, 1.05980790705, 1.0438431988799999, 1.02497712333, 1.00659505173, 0.98919173016, 0.9715707328300001, 0.95416868081, 0.9416231916500001, 0.92753217501, 0.91364512326, 0.90414607963, 0.8947884227199999, 0.8843405703999998, 0.8769049253500001, 0.8719632452999999, 0.86833484662, 0.8680955887799999, 0.86604049098, 0.86558996362, 0.86372701427, 0.85893691627, 0.85435131048, 0.84886228665, 0.8409088095199999, 0.82732292967, 0.8182398235399999, 0.81298593645, 0.8065804672500001, 0.7963832009099999, 0.7813524576499999, 0.7642633939500001, 0.74891606863, 0.73387495429, 0.72021307831, 0.70711249145, 0.6972523931, 0.68836254874, 0.6789805168, 0.66917573095, 0.65520369872, 0.6405349086200001, 0.6262600443299999, 0.6128265668199999, 0.6004827768800001, 0.58821246352, 0.5763513298499999, 0.56580466895, 0.55820613325, 0.5498382224900001, 0.5432313079700001, 0.5383656045, 0.53169802591];
```

Here are some additional values for the pow dataset:

(Link to pastebin to not exceed post length limit)
https://pastebin.com/5GP8sj4N

The resulting fit that from the trial dataset (x, pow1) I get is shown here (orange) with the original (pow1) data (blue)

[image: Fit of Data]

As mentioned, there is an issue with how the phase fits the minima and maxima. Unfortunately the application of getting this fit function correct has very little room for error.

Please help out if you have an idea of how to make this fit the data better!

Edit:
I tried what @Joe mentioned in the comments, with first filtering the data. I utilized a Savitzky-Golay filter and recieved the following result, Original data (blue), the filtered data (green), and the fit to the filtered data (orange). Again the same shift in minima and maxima is still present in the fit function to the filtered data.

[image: Filtered and fitted data]

Comment: I tried splicing your separate code  snippets together, guessing at import statements - and after adding in graphing code, I visually have the the same fit, though I cannot compare fitted values as you did not post those. What is the issue with phase?

Comment: You could first lowpass filter the data. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html Or you could make a Fourier transformation identifying the frequency and phase of the sine wave.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks for looking through this. You can see from the figure that the minimum point of the raw data is fairly smooth, with what should be a minima around 5.65 but the fit function does not reflect this, with a minima around 5.5. I am hoping to somehow get a tighter fit to the data since my application of this final fit-function necessitates high tolerance with the original raw data.

Comment: @Joe please see my answer to this question. I welcome any comments, thoughts, or suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my results with more aggressive clipping bounds of 0.5 to 1.75 for each data set.

for pow1:

[image: pow1]

```
A =  9.6711505138648990E-01
c =  9.7613787086912507E-01
p =  4.0262076448344617E+00
w =  1.2654001570670070E+00
```

for pow2:

[image: pow2]

```
A =  9.4894637490866129E-01
c =  9.6733405789489280E-01
p =  4.0892433833755097E+00
w =  1.2578627414445132E+00
```

for pow3:

[image: pow3]

```
A =  9.8595630272060597E-01
c =  9.6749868212694512E-01
p =  4.0859456191316230E+00
w =  1.2598547148182329E+00
```

for pow4:

[image: pow4]

```
A = -9.4636707498392481E-01
c =  9.5047597808408602E-01
p = -4.2643913461857056E+02
w =  1.2761107231684055E+00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this figured out - your data is not a mathematically perfect sine wave + noise, so the fitting software can only come close to modeling a sine function to this data. If you must have more accuracy, try splitting the model into different segments and use a piecewise fit. Here is a close-up of the problem area:

[image: plot]

Comment: This makes sense. Is is possible to omit these flatlined data-points and fit as I am currently doing to everything above, say 0.11? I am imaging for subsequent datasets I can write a function to identify when this pattern is happening then and omit the points.

Comment: Maybe, but this should not cause the shift in the phase, right?

Comment: You can try clipping off the bottom, say, 10 percent of the peak-to-peak value. That should fit OK based on this data set.

Comment: @JamesPhillips It seems that after trying to remove the lower 10% or, masking it off using numpy.ma.masked_outside (or similar) that the curve fit is exactly the same as it would be without masking off the data. Strangely, when I also tried to apply the scipy.signal.savgol_filter to smooth the data, the curve fit is still the same as it would be before the smoothing. The phase-shift is seemingly still present. I would use the filtered data as-is but I need fairly arbitrary precision of being able to plug in x and get out y. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I have added a second answer to display my results from more aggressive clipping.